# Chai Sinon, should.have.been flags are undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

Many apologies for the title, I'm still thinking of a better way to explain this.

I'm having an issue in Chai when calling should.have.been. , where the propert always returns undefined.  The weird thing is I'm doing a console.log(should.have.been) , and it prints the full object, but for some reason I can't access the flags.

example.js under test

```
var var BaseController = function (model, routesFn) {
    var router = require('express').Router();
    routesFn(router);

    return router;
};
```

test.js

```
var controller = require('../lib/controller.js')
,assert = require("assert")
,chai = require('chai')
,sinon = require('sinon')
,should = chai.should();


describe('baseController', function() {
  it('should have something..', function() {

    var routesFn = sinon.spy();
    controller(null, routesFn);

    routesFn.should.have.not.been.called;   //notice the 'not'.  
                                            //Should fail here, but called is undefined
    assert.equal(routesFn.called, true);

  });
});
```

So, I'm able to verify that the callback 'routesFn' is invoked by using the assert.equa(), but for some reason the called property is showing undefined.  I was initially trying to create a test using the chai should have been called syntax, and later realized that my tests would pass even when I didn't have the logic implemented.

When I do a console.log of the object I see this

```
console.log(routesFn.should.have.not.been);


{ __flags:
   { ssfi: [Function: shouldGetter],
     object:
      { [Function: proxy]
       reset: [Function],
       invoke: [Function: invoke],
       named: [Function: named],
       ...
       called: true
    }
}
```

When I do a console out of 'called' , it prints undefined.  Obviously I can't access the nested property.

```
console.log(routesFn.should.have.not.been.called);  //expecting to print true

//prints
undefined
```

So, am I missing something in the initial setup?  I was thinking I need to add something else to the 'should' variable initialization, but can't find anything on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chai itself does not have support for what you are trying to do.

I presume what you call `example.js` should be `controller.js` and should be something like:

```
module.exports = function (model, routesFn) {
    var router = require('express').Router();
    routesFn(router);

    return router;
};
```

Otherwise, I can't see how you code can work at all. Using the module above, the only thing I need to change to your `test.js` file is to add this after the require calls you already have, and after the call to `chai.should()`:

```
var sinonChai = require('sinon-chai');
chai.use(sinonChai);
```

**[`sinon-chai`](https://github.com/domenic/sinon-chai) is what adds support for `should.have.not.been.called`.** With this in place, your test fails as you expect.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I missed this was actually part of sinon-chai.  Sorry, was a long night and overlooked this line `chai.use(sinonChai);`